# maven-checkstyle-plugin failed to parse Java 'record'

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I'm trying to setup checkstyle in our project - but seems like `Maven` (v3.8.3) or `maven-checkstyle-plugin` (v3.1.1) itself are not aware of Java 14's `record` (we use Java 17).

```html
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /Users/dmitry.adonin/IdeaProjects/raap/src/main/java/com/xxx/web/dto/Request.java:3:8: unexpected token: record
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.JavaParser$1.reportError (JavaParser.java:93)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.grammar.GeneratedJavaRecognizer.typeDefinition (GeneratedJavaRecognizer.java:411)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.grammar.GeneratedJavaRecognizer.compilationUnit (GeneratedJavaRecognizer.java:202)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.JavaParser.parse (JavaParser.java:99)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.processFiltered (TreeWalker.java:159)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AbstractFileSetCheck.process (AbstractFileSetCheck.java:85)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.processFile (Checker.java:329)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.processFiles (Checker.java:291)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.process (Checker.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.exec.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle (DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute (CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.java:545)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: record
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.grammar.GeneratedJavaRecognizer.typeDefinitionInternal (GeneratedJavaRecognizer.java:584)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.grammar.GeneratedJavaRecognizer.typeDefinition (GeneratedJavaRecognizer.java:389)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.grammar.GeneratedJavaRecognizer.compilationUnit (GeneratedJavaRecognizer.java:202)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.JavaParser.parse (JavaParser.java:99)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.processFiltered (TreeWalker.java:159)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AbstractFileSetCheck.process (AbstractFileSetCheck.java:85)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.processFile (Checker.java:329)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.processFiles (Checker.java:291)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.process (Checker.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.exec.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle (DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute (CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.java:545)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

There are the following configs:

`pom.xml`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>...</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>project-checks.xml</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>checkstyle-validation</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`project-checks.xml`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<!--
    Checkstyle configuration that checks the Google coding conventions from Google Java Style
    that can be found at https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html
    Checkstyle is very configurable. Be sure to read the documentation at
    https://checkstyle.org (or in your downloaded distribution).
    To completely disable a check, just comment it out or delete it from the file.
    To suppress certain violations please review suppression filters.
    Authors: Max Vetrenko, Ruslan Diachenko, Roman Ivanov.
 -->

<module name = "Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="severity" value="error"/>

    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
    <!-- Excludes all 'module-info.java' files              -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_filefilters.html -->
    <module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
        <property name="fileNamePattern" value="module\-info\.java$"/>
    </module>
    <!-- Checks new line at end of file is required                     -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_misc.html#NewlineAtEndOfFile -->
    <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
        <property name="lineSeparator" value="lf"/>
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, xml, yml, yaml"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Checks for whitespace                            -->
    <!-- See http://checkstyle.org/config_whitespace.html -->
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>

    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
        <property name="max" value="200"/>
        <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
    </module>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
        <module name="IllegalTokenText">
            <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL, CHAR_LITERAL"/>
            <property name="format"
                      value="\\u00(09|0(a|A)|0(c|C)|0(d|D)|22|27|5(C|c))|\\(0(10|11|12|14|15|42|47)|134)"/>
            <property name="message"
                      value="Consider using special escape sequence instead of octal value or Unicode escaped value."/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters">
            <property name="allowEscapesForControlCharacters" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowByTailComment" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowNonPrintableEscapes" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="UnusedImports"/>
        <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
        <module name="NoLineWrap">
            <property name="tokens" value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyBlock">
            <property name="option" value="TEXT"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NeedBraces">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_WHILE"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LeftCurly">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="ANNOTATION_DEF, CLASS_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                    INTERFACE_DEF, LAMBDA, LITERAL_CASE, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DEFAULT,
                    LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF,
                    LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_DEF,
                    OBJBLOCK, STATIC_INIT"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RightCurly">
            <property name="id" value="RightCurlySame"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE,
                    LITERAL_DO"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RightCurly">
            <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
            <property name="option" value="alone"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, STATIC_INIT,
                    INSTANCE_INIT, ANNOTATION_DEF, ENUM_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SuppressionXpathSingleFilter">
            <!-- suppresion is required till https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/7541 -->
            <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
            <property name="query" value="//RCURLY[parent::SLIST[count(./*)=1]
                                                 or preceding-sibling::*[last()][self::LCURLY]]"/>
        </module>
        <module name="WhitespaceAround">
            <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyLambdas" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyTypes" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyLoops" value="true"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="ASSIGN, BAND, BAND_ASSIGN, BOR, BOR_ASSIGN, BSR, BSR_ASSIGN, BXOR,
                    BXOR_ASSIGN, COLON, DIV, DIV_ASSIGN, DO_WHILE, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAMBDA, LAND,
                    LCURLY, LE, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY,
                    LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_RETURN, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,
                     LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, LOR, LT, MINUS, MINUS_ASSIGN, MOD, MOD_ASSIGN,
                     NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, PLUS_ASSIGN, QUESTION, RCURLY, SL, SLIST, SL_ASSIGN, SR,
                     SR_ASSIGN, STAR, STAR_ASSIGN, LITERAL_ASSERT, TYPE_EXTENSION_AND"/>
            <message key="ws.notFollowed"
                     value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not followed by whitespace. Empty blocks may only be represented as '{}' when not part of a multi-block statement (4.1.3)"/>
            <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                     value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
        </module>
        <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
        <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
        <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
        <module name="FallThrough"/>
        <module name="UpperEll"/>
        <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
        <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                    STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
            <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLines" value="false"/>
            <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLinesInsideClassMembers" value="false"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapDot"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="DOT"/>
            <property name="option" value="nl"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapComma"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="COMMA"/>
            <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <!-- ELLIPSIS is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/258 -->
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapEllipsis"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="ELLIPSIS"/>
            <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <!-- ARRAY_DECLARATOR is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/259 -->
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapArrayDeclarator"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_DECLARATOR"/>
            <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapMethodRef"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_REF"/>
            <property name="option" value="nl"/>
        </module>
        <module name="PackageName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Package name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="TypeName">
            <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, ANNOTATION_DEF"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="MemberName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Member name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="LambdaParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Lambda parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="CatchParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Catch parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="LocalVariableName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Local variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)|(^[A-Z]{1,2})$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Class type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Method type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)|(^[A-Z]{1,2})$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Interface type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Method name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
        <module name="GenericWhitespace">
            <message key="ws.followed"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is followed by whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.preceded"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is preceded with whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.illegalFollow"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' should followed by whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
        </module>
        <module name="Indentation">
            <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
            <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
            <property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
            <property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
            <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="4"/>
            <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName">
            <property name="ignoreFinal" value="false"/>
            <property name="allowedAbbreviationLength" value="3"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, ANNOTATION_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF,
                    PARAMETER_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF, METHOD_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
        <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>
        <module name="CustomImportOrder">
            <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE###SPECIAL_IMPORTS###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###STATIC"/>
            <property name="specialImportsRegExp" value="^javax\."/>
            <property name="standardPackageRegExp" value="^java\."/>
            <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="false"/>
            <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, PACKAGE_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodParamPad">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_NEW, METHOD_CALL, METHOD_DEF,
                    SUPER_CTOR_CALL, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="COMMA, SEMI, POST_INC, POST_DEC, DOT, ELLIPSIS, METHOD_REF"/>
            <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParenPad">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="ANNOTATION, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, CTOR_CALL, CTOR_DEF, DOT, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF,
                    EXPR, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_NEW,
                    LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_CALL,
                    METHOD_DEF, QUESTION, RESOURCE_SPECIFICATION, SUPER_CTOR_CALL, LAMBDA"/>
        </module>
        <module name="OperatorWrap">
            <property name="option" value="NL"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR,
                    LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR, METHOD_REF "/>
        </module>
        <module name="AnnotationLocation">
            <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationMostCases"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AnnotationLocation">
            <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationVariables"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
            <property name="allowSamelineMultipleAnnotations" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
        <module name="InvalidJavadocPosition"/>
        <module name="JavadocTagContinuationIndentation"/>
        <module name="SummaryJavadoc">
            <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments"
                      value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocParagraph"/>
        <module name="AtclauseOrder">
            <property name="tagOrder" value="@param, @return, @throws, @deprecated"/>
            <property name="target"
                      value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocMethod">
            <property name="scope" value="public"/>
            <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SingleLineJavadoc">
            <property name="ignoreInlineTags" value="false"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyCatchBlock">
            <property name="exceptionVariableName" value="expected"/>
        </module>
        <module name="CommentsIndentation">
            <property name="tokens" value="SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT, BLOCK_COMMENT_BEGIN"/>
        </module>
        <!-- https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter -->
        <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
            <property name="file" value="checkstyle-xpath-suppressions.xml"/>
            <property name="optional" value="true"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

Could someone please suggest what should be adjusted to make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin by default comes with Checkstyle version 8.29. Try explicitly defining the CheckStyle version (plus a small version bump to 3.1.2). For example, with version 9.2:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
       ...
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped - I see the check result. You saved my day :)

Comment: This does not work if checkstyle is executed from the `sonar-maven-plugin` by SonarSource. Do you possibly know how to enforce the version there? Since the plugin itself does not depend (directly or transitively) on any checkstyle library, there's no point in overriding the dependency. I was unable to find out, how they execute checkstyle without referencing it anywhere.

Comment: @inkassso perhaps the `sonar-maven-plugin` defines its own checkstyle configuration. You could try adding the same dependency to that plugin.